# Node command line verbose output

Tags: javascript, node.js, command-line

So I'm running

`sudo node app.js`

```
var express = require("express");
var app = express();


app.get("/",function(req,res){
        res.send("<h1>Oi mate</h1>");
});

app.listen(80);
```

And the process freezes

How do I see the output like other command line tools would have `--verbose`

Comment: Why do you need sudo. It would be helpful if you can provide some information on whats inside app.js

Comment: *"How do I see the output like other command line tools would have `--verbose`"* Every CLI is different. Assuming you wrote `app.js` yourself, you have to explicitly implement support for a `--verbose` command line argument.

Comment: @FelixKling got it. So odds are it is freezing on app.js rather than node itself?

Comment: @Chamindu the OP listens to port 80 and this is a protected port on most systems, so thats most likely the reason why `sudo` is used here.

Comment: @EricJohnson Why do you think it is freezing? You tell it to listen on port 80 and wait for get requests, so did you try to request `http://localhost/` so see if it returns `<h1>Oi mate</h1>`?

Comment: @t.niese Looks like it works. \o/. I thought it was freezing because there was no output. Most web frameworks I've worked with output some basic information about the server running

Comment: [`app.listen(port, [hostname], [backlog], [callback])`](http://expressjs.com/en/4x/api.html#app.listen), accepts a callback as last parameter, that tells you if an error occurred or if your server is running. [express: Hello world example](http://expressjs.com/en/starter/hello-world.html)

Comment: if you wanna write that as a answer ill gladly accept @t.niese

Comment: Your question is not "why is my app freezing?" ... If you accept the answer as you say, please change the question title. The original question is a good one... and still not answered.

Answer (score 79):

You can enable verbose logging in all core modules with the following commandline form:

```
NODE_DEBUG=cluster,net,http,fs,tls,module,timers node app.js
```

Comment: A breath of fresh air! I can see again!

Comment: Just a small addition - On windows you can run the following:
`set NODE_DEBUG=cluster,net,http,fs,tls,module,timers & node app.js`