# How to catch an error when axios suddenly stops working in nodejs?

Tags: node.js, axios

I have a small code that checks the performance of the proxy server. In most cases, it works normally. However, in some cases I get unstable work

```js
async function controllerCheckingProxy(proxy, url) {
  let proxy_agent = await proxyToLink(proxy);
  console.log("checking 1");
  const axiosDefaultConfig = {
    timeout: 2500,
    proxy: false,
    httpsAgent: new HttpsProxyAgent(proxy_agent),
  };
  console.log("checking 2");
  const axios = require("axios").create(axiosDefaultConfig);
  console.log("checking 3");
  return await axios
    .get(url, {
      headers: {
        "User-Agent":
          "Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 6.3; Win64; x64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/62.0.3202.89 Safari/537.36",
      },
    })
    .then(function (response) {
      console.log("checking 4");
      console.log("[INFO]: Proxy testing is successful: " + proxy_agent);
      return true;
    })
    .catch(function (error) {
      console.log("checking 5");
      console.log("[INFO]: Proxy testing is fail: " + proxy_agent);
      console.log(error);
      return false;
    })
    .finally(function () {
      console.log("checking 6");
      return false;
    });
}
```

The instability lies in the fact that at some point the console just exits the application

> $ checking 1

> $ checking 2

> $ checking 3

Complete exit from the script to the command line shell. There are no errors, there is no console.log output, there is nothing. Control returned to the shell. The behavior is very similar to as if after the lines `console.log('checking 3');` it was written `process.exit();`

Simply not executed `.then .catch .finally` - but why?
Any thoughts on how you can understand what the problem is? or how to catch such a situation - the script works correctly in 90%, but in the remaining 10% it completes without an error

*node v16*

Comment: Why do you return `axios.get` instead of just calling it?

Comment: @Geshode presumably so the `controllerCheckingProxy` function returns a promise that resolves with the Axios request

Comment: @Phil But wouldn't the `await` be unneeded then? If you want to return a promise.

Comment: @Geshode true, the `await` is redundant.

Comment: How are you calling `controllerCheckingProxy()` and what are you doing with the result? FYI the return value from `finally()` is not used

Comment: @Phil I'm calling her ```let check = await controllerCheckingProxy(params,params);```

Comment: Tried wrapping that in a `try..catch`? For example... `try { let check = await controllerCheckingProxy(params,params); } catch (err) { console.error(err); }`

Comment: @Phil - there is nothing, exactly the same behavior, there is no error, it just ends and that's it, I ran it twice, the first time I checked 5 proxies and stopped, the second time I didn't even check 1 proxy immediately stopped. - I can't even imagine how to find the problem

Comment: Only other advice I'd offer is to run `node` with [debug logging](https://stackoverflow.com/a/46858827/283366)